# Refresacar un Combo Box en VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

tengo un problema (quizas muy simple) pero que no he podido solucionar, resulta que estoy haciendo un form para registros en Visual Basic .Net, dentro del mismo tengo combobox que cuando cargo el form por primera vez todo está a la perfección pero al realizar un registro tengo que limpar los campos(textBox) y actualizar el comboBox del form pero no me realiza la tarea como yo quisiera (Me deja el combobox en blanco).
El metodo limpiar hago lo siguiente

```
Public Sub limpiarCampos()
        txtRFC.Text = ""
        txtCodigoCiudadano.Text = ""
        cboTipoAccionista.SelectedIndex = -1
end sub
```

Agradezco mucho la sugerencia que me puedan brindar, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor incluye un [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Silvestre,

El problema es que haciendo lo que nos muestras, no estás limpiando el `DataSource` del `ComboBox`, simplemente le estás indicando que no tenga seleccionado ningún `Item`.

Para vaciar el `ComboBox` de datos lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

Si el ComboBox lo has llenado con un `DataBound (DataSource)` debes poner lo siguiente:

```
cboTipoAccionista.DataSource = null;
```

Por lo contrario, si no lo has llenado con un `DataBound (DataSource)` debes poner la siguiente instrucción:

```
cboTipoAccionista.Items.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es que el combo muestre un valor, en lugar de -1 pon el index del valor que necesitas(`cboTipoAccionista.SelectedIndex = 0`).

Si quieres refrescar los valores que contiene, carga tu combo en un método
(mismo que vas a ejecutar en el Load) y manda a llamar el método después de limpiar.